# is there a way to open a new window in the background?

Tags: jquery, html

I am wondering if there's some kind of way to open a new window directly in the background of a browser?

```
<a href=# target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Javascript:

```
function open2(url, opt){
   if (opt == 0) // current window
     window.location = url;
   else if (opt == 1) // new window
     window.open(url);
   else if (opt == 2) // background window
     {
        window.open(url); 
        self.focus();
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.